# How do I set non-fixed dimensions on an angular ui grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I found how to turn off scrolling but this doesn't make all the rows show up like a flat table of data.

```
$scope.gridOptions.enableHorizontalScrollbar = uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER;
$scope.gridOptions.enableVerticalScrollbar = uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER;
```

Is there a way to use [ng-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection) as an inline-block element that always takes the size of its children regardless of how tall or wide they are?

Comment: That's been a popular request from a number of people. It's planned but not complete yet.

Comment: Thanks for the update @c0bra - I'm still pretty new to Angular otherwise I would look into contributing the feature myself.  Maybe I'll give it a go anyway because the worst that could happen is I learn something...

Comment: Great attitude!  There's some docs on contributing in the github repo:https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md